# Object literal key value as type (Typescript). Am I doing it right/the right thing?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have literal object and I want to be able to use it as a param in function, e.g.

```
const SOCIAL_PROVIDER = {
  Google: 'Google',
  Facebook: 'Facebook'
}

handle(SOCIAL_PROVIDER.Google) // OK
handle(SOCIAL_PROVIDER.Twitter) // want TS to throw error
handle('Google') // want TS to throw error
```

Then comes the function signature type, the only way I make it work is as following

```
type SocialProvider = {
  Google: 'Google',
  Facebook: 'Facebook'
};

const SOCIAL_PROVIDER: SocialProvider = {
  Google: 'Google',
  Facebook: 'Facebook'
};

type handle = (value: keyof typeof SOCIAL_PROVIDER) => void
```

Am I doing it right or approach this correctly? Or there is a better way?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered [enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)?

Comment: "the only way I make it work" would still allow `handle("Google")`, right?  It does seem like you want an enum here.

Answer (score 0):

Use TypeScript [Enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html):

```ts
enum SocialProvider = {
  Google: 'Google',
  Facebook: 'Facebook'
};

type handle = (value: SocialProvider) => void
```

Example:

```ts
const func: handle = value => {
  // Do something
}

func(SocialProvider.Google);
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think just creating a Type with your Providers is nice and simple..

eg..

```
type SOCIAL_PROVIDER = 'Google' | 'Facebook';
const SOCIAL_PROVIDER_HANDLE: Record<SOCIAL_PROVIDER, string> = {
  Facebook: 'FB',
  Google: 'GOOGLE'
}

function handle(provider: SOCIAL_PROVIDER) {
  console.log(SOCIAL_PROVIDER_HANDLE[provider]);  
}

handle('Google') // OK
handle('Twitter') // want TS to throw error
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0&ssl=13&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg8gYQJIEEAyB9ACgJTgNSQBEBRHKAXigHIBxAe3oHMAbCaqAHxoDEBDAMYQARowDW1ANwAoAfQB2AZ2CxEqTLgLEyGABIoAckTQkAXFBwQ5AJwAmAHnjJ02PIVI4ANFGXWAlvJMAHyUUADe0lBQ-EKi9GLm1DwAQtSekVAMzGyJtHBwtCbU0gC%200tIAZgCu8gLAfgpQABZ88rZsABRg1vQAbn62ENbmTuquWh4AlOEZckr0bAB0LMwdoy6a7jr6RiYA2t19A0MAupOSUaXlLW2ddIys7NMA9M9QcADS0jftEB3UABUAO5%20YDAIbUF5vIGtFQAmBQYD0RFNHpAqBDHrWcpAA)

Another idea if you want to keep things DRY,.  eg.  in the above `Google` and `Facebook` get repeated, you could let TS build the type for you.

eg.

```
const SOCIAL_PROVIDER_HANDLE = {
  Facebook: 'FB',
  Google: 'GOOGLE'
};

type SOCIAL_PROVIDER = keyof typeof SOCIAL_PROVIDER_HANDLE;

function handle(provider: SOCIAL_PROVIDER) {
  console.log(SOCIAL_PROVIDER_HANDLE[provider]);  
}

handle('Google') // OK
handle('Twitter') // want TS to throw error
```

Comment: Yeah this was my initial version and still prefer it but I need to use this **handle** function in quite a few places. If I ever need to change the value, e.g. 'Google' to 'GOOGLE' I need to find and replace all over.

Comment: @CuongNguyen  In that case I would create a const of handles, updated answer.  The great thing with all this, is that code completion works nice and simple, and the output JS is cleaner than enums.  You don't need to import any Enum either, as would be the case if using enums..

Comment: It's worth pointing out,  Enums in Typescript some see them as mistake, as it diverted away from any ES standard.  If Enum didn't currently exist in TS, they wouldn't be implemented now.  As Typescript is not meant to extend Javascript syntax, and just deal with typing.  Also enums can give issues with typing, more info here -> https://thoughtbot.com/blog/the-trouble-with-typescript-enums

Comment: It does not seem to work with your updated answer. 
`handle(SOCIAL_PROVIDER_HANDLE['Google']) // error`

Comment: @CuongNguyen  It works for me in the TS playground,  `Twitter` shows as an error, and when you run it shows `GOOGLE`...

Comment: @CuongNguyen  Updated again to make it more obvious.

Comment: Sure it works with literal type but the thing is I want another way that not literal type. Basically `handle(SOCIAL_PROVIDER_HANDLE.Google)` or somewhat similar.

Seems like enum might help here but yeah it sucks VSCode suggestion breaks all the time for me with Enum

Comment: @CuongNguyen  Ok, that's up to you.  But I'm not sure what is it you think your gaining by having to put `SOCIAL_PROVIDER_HANDLE.Google` instead of `'Google'`?..